# How can I make ng-change to work for same values as well?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJs. **My problem is:** I have a dropdown box and a textbox. I am selecting some value from the dropdown box and `ng-change` fires and also the dropdown box gets to its default value when someone starts typing in the textbox. Now after the dropdown is reset, if I again select the same value in dropdown which I selected previously then `ng-change` does not get fired.

I used `ng-click` also for this but it doesn't work in all browsers then. I am stuck with this problem.

Is there any way make `ng-change` to work on the same value as the previous one or some alternative?

**My Code Snippet :**

```
    <code>
    <input class="form-control" type="text"  id="city1" onblur="codeAddress();" name="city1"  ng-model="city1" required>
    <select class="form-control" id="brandC" name="brandC" ng-model="vehicle.companyId"  ng-change="selectServiceCenter();" required>
    <option ng-selected="loginbrandId1==null" value='' >Select Your Car</option>
    <option  ng-selected="loginbrandId1 == vehicle.companyId" ng-repeat="vehicle in vehiclenames"   value='{{vehicle.companyId}},{{vehicle.vehicleID}}' >{{vehicle.companyName}}--{{vehicle.vehicleNumber}}</option>
    </select>
    <script>
$scope.watchHitCountcity = 0;
    $scope.$watch('city1', function (newValue, oldValue) {

        if(newValue!=undefined)
            {
             document.getElementById("brandC").value= "";
            }
        $scope.watchHitCountcity++;
    },true);
    $scope.selectServiceCenter = function() {
    alert("execute");
    }
    </script>
    </code>
```

Comment: a plunker would be great !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Reason behind your problem**

What's happening in your case is you just removed the value from the dropdown using native java script `document.getElementById("brandC").value= "";`,but this doesn't change the value of ng-model of that element which is `ng-model="vehicle.companyId"`.Because the ng-model of the dropdown has not changed the `ng-change="selectServiceCenter();"` function doesn't gets triggered as for angular still the ng-model is the same.

**Solution**

So change your below code like below as suggested by @Sandeep

```
$scope.vehicle ={}; //create vehicle object in scope..
$scope.$watch('city1', function (newValue, oldValue) {

        if(newValue!=undefined && newValue!=oldValue){
             $scope.vehicle.companyId = null;
            }
        $scope.watchHitCountcity++;
 },true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation . I applied it but now it gives an error as below:Error: $scope.vehicle is undefined
@http://localhost:8080/carservice/resources/js/angular/angularProfile.js:133:6
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/carservice/reso

Comment: update my answer ! create $scope.vehicle ={}; object in your controller and try doing it now

Comment: glad I could help you !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use **document.getElementById("brandC").value= "";** use **ng-model**
like :

```
$scope.$watch('city1', function (newValue, oldValue) {

        if(newValue!=undefined)
            {
             vehicle.companyId = "";
            }
        $scope.watchHitCountcity++;
 },true);
```